# If I run tmux and then `kill` the tmux process, I see two bash processes. How does this second bash relate to the first and how do I kill it?

Tags: bash, tmux, kill, ps, session

As stated in the question, I'm trying to better understand sessions, processes, process groups, etc. A few questions that I came across while playing around with tmux.

1. If I open tmux and run ps, I see two bash processes. If I understand correctly, one bash process corresponds to the parent shell and the second bash process is the one that tmux opened?
2. If I `kill` the tmux process, the terminal appears to go back to the parent shell, but then if I run ps again, I see two bash processes. My guess is that this second bash process was the one that tmux opened but that I'm no longer connected to on this terminal? How does this second bash process relate to the first one in terms of process groups and sessions?
3. How do I `kill` this second bash process? Running `kill` with the PID doesn't seem to do anything. Also is there a way to detach my terminal from one shell and switch to the another?
4. If I were to `Ctrl+D` with tmux open, both tmux and the second bash process exit properly. Is that because tmux sends a signal to end the bash process before tmux closes? Why does this work better than `kill`.

I was running tmux from a bash shell on my terminal in macOS. I type tmux from the shell to run it. As soon as tmux opens in the terminal, I run ps. When I get the pid of tmux, I run kill [pid] and then run ps again. I've never configured tmux so I suppose the .tmuxrc file will still be at its default.

Comment: Where are you running tmux from? What commands are you running **exactly**? (Where are you typing them, and with what options?) And copy-paste their output. Also if you have any relevant shell aliases (e.g. something that would pass options to `ps`) mention that. And if you have a `.tmuxrc`, post it as well.

Comment: Hey I was running tmux from a bash shell on my terminal in macOS. I type `tmux` from the shell to run it. As soon as tmux opens in the terminal, I run `ps`. When I get the pid of tmux, I run `kill [pid]` and then run `ps` again. I've never configured tmux so I suppose the `.tmuxrc` file will still be at its default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step 1: run tmux

Initially, you have a terminal open, with bash running in it. I'll call this the original bash.

You run `tmux` from the original bash. Tmux runs two processes: the tmux server and the tmux client. The reason it does that is that you can detach from a tmux session and reattach to it later — this is a core feature of tmux. The tmux client connects to the terminal where the session is attached. The server runs the processes running in the tmux windows. When you detach from a session (`C-b d`), the client exits, but the server and the processes running in the session keep running. In addition to the two tmux processes, assuming you haven't started a tmux session yet, `tmux` creates a new session containing one window where it runs your shell: that's the second bash.

At this point, the relevant part of the process tree looks like this:

```
…
        ├─tmux: server───bash───pstree
        └─xterm───bash───tmux: client
```

This is from the `pstree` command on Linux. To get a similar display on macOS, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/linux-ps-f-tree-view-equivalent-on-osx. `xterm` is the terminal where I ran my original bash, and `tmux: client` is the tmux client started by running `tmux` in the original bash. `tmux: server` is the tmux server that the tmux client started, and its child `bash` is the second bash, where I ran `pstree` from.

On Linux, here's the output of `ps` inside tmux:

```
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
    108 pts/56   00:00:00 bash
    153 pts/56   00:00:00 ps
```

By default, Linux's `ps` only shows the processes that are running on the current terminal. That's why I see. On FreeBSD, and I expect also on macOS (I ran this on a machine where my shell is zsh, that's why it shows zsh rather than bash):

```
19690  0  Is   0:00.36 /usr/local/bin/zsh
20046  0  I+   0:00.01 tmux: client (/tmp//tmux-1001/default) (tmux)
20049  1  Rs   0:00.06 /usr/local/bin/zsh
20138  1  R+   0:00.01 ps
```

The reason the BSD `ps` shows more processes is that by default, it shows processes that are attached to any terminal. (The technical term is processes that “have a controlling terminal”.) It doesn't show processes that are not attached to a terminal at all, such as the tmux server.

To see all the processes involved and to get more information about these processes, let's run `ps` with a few options. The options to see the relevant data are slightly different on different unix variants. I'll show Linux and FreeBSD; macOS is probably close to FreeBSD but may be a little different. On Linux, here's the output of `ps x -o pid,ppid,tty,comm f`, filtered to the relevant processes:

```
    PID    PPID TT      COMMAND
    107       1 ?       tmux: server
    108     107 pts/1    \_ bash
    154     108 pts/1        \_ ps
      3       1 ?       xterm
      6       3 pts/0    \_ bash
    105       6 pts/0        \_ tmux: client
```

And on FreeBSD, with `ps -U $(id -u) -A -o pid,ppid,tty,command -d` (on macOS you'll need to remove `-d` and you won't get the tree presentation) (again filtered; on FreeBSD I'm logged in remotely so the original zsh is in a terminal provided by `sshd`):

```
  PID  PPID TTY   COMMAND
19689 19687 -     sshd: gilles@pts/0 (sshd)
19690 19689 pts/0 - /usr/local/bin/zsh
20046 19690 pts/0 `-- tmux: client (/tmp//tmux-1001/default) (tmux)
20048     1 -     tmux: server (/tmp//tmux-1001/default) (tmux)
20049 20048 pts/1 - /usr/local/bin/zsh
20149 20049 pts/1 `-- ps -U 1001 -A -o pid,ppid,tty,command -d
```

In both case you can see six processes:

- The terminal emulator that provides `pts/0`.
- The original shell, running in `pts/0`.
- The tmux client, running in `pts/0`, started from the original shell.
- The tmux server. It isn't running in a terminal. Its parent (`PPID`) is process 1. (This happens because when the tmux client starts the server, it double-forks: it creates a child process which itself creates child process, then exits immediately. When the intermediate process exits, the grandchild becomes orphaned and is therefore adopted by [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), which is process 1.)
- The shell running inside tmux. It's running inside the single tmux window, which is the terminal `pts/1`.
- `ps` running inside the shell inside tmux.

### Step 2: kill tmux

You kill the tmux process. But which one? We saw above that there are two. We also saw above that on macOS, `ps` with no options shows all processes that are running in a terminal. So you saw, and killed, the tmux client. This is equivalent to detaching from the session. The tmux server is still running. That's one of the reasons to use tmux: if the client is killed, for example because the terminal where the client is running goes away, the session keeps running.

### Step 3: reattach the session

You can see the existing tmux session with `tmux list-sessions`. And you can reattach to it with `tmux attach`. If you have several sessions, you can choose which one to attach to by passing the session number after `tmux attach`, e.g. `tmux attach 0` to attach to the session that `tmux list-sessions` describes as `0: 1 windows (created …) …`.

If you want to kill the session without attaching to it, you can use `tmux kill-session`. There's even a command `tmux kill-server` which kills all the sessions.

### Step 4: normal exit

When you press Ctrl+D or enter `exit` in the shell inside tmux, the shell exits. When the main process of a tmux window exits, tmux closes the window. When tmux closes the last window, the session exits.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, the distinction between the `tmux: client` and `tmux: server` and how to find them via `ps` is illuminating. One note though is that my output from running `ps -U $(id -u) -A -o pid,ppid,tty,command -d` on macOS looks quite different — the `-d` flag actually filters out the `tmux`, `ps`, `bash` processes. But by running `ps -A` I can see the relevant processes. In addition, instead of being named `tmux: server` and `tmux: client`, they're both just called `tmux`, but I can identify the server as the one with `PPID = 1` .

Comment: @NNNComplex Ok, thanks for the information. I don't have macOS to check. There's probably a way to see `tmux: client/server` on macOS but it may require a different column name, maybe `comm` like on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Fedora 32 with default settings.

> If I open tmux and run ps, I see two bash processes.

tmux itself is a child of bash, however it needs to provide you with an independent shell (that's the whole point of the application - being able to detach sessions), so it spawns another bash instance.

> If I kill the tmux process, the terminal appears to go back to the parent shell, but then if I run ps again, I see two bash processes

That depends on how you kill it.

tmux spawns its own child which then spawns a shell.

If you kill the child tmux, the child bash should terminate and you will be left with a single bash process.

If you kill the parent tmux, the child tmux will keep on running with the bash process under it, i.e. you'll get two bash processes.

Comment: `ps` without options wouldn't show the bash process that tmux ran from: by default `ps` only shows processes running on the current terminal. But it's not clear from the question whether NNNComplex ran `ps`, or perhaps `ps` with options.

Comment: I assumed he always ran `ps fax` which is what I use.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, I ran `kill [pid]` from inside the tmux shell. I got the pid from running `ps` without any flags inside the tmux shell (and I only saw one process, albeit this is on macOS). How can I know whether I was kililng the child or parent tmux process?

Comment: I've no idea how to view the process tree in MacOS X. In Linux that's `ps fax`. Looks like it's quite complicated: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/linux-ps-f-tree-view-equivalent-on-osx https://serverfault.com/questions/324945/what-is-the-os-x-bsd-equivalent-of-the-gnu-ps-auxf-command

Comment: So the explanation about `ps` is that the BSD/macOS `ps` is not POSIX compliant and displays all processes with a controlling terminal by default, not just the ones on the current terminal. By the way `ps -d` on FreeBSD is similar to `ps f` on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The `tmux` environment is a bit of a special case in regards to understanding sessions, mostly since it's designed to be. Normally, when you kill a process, all of it's children processes are reaped (killed) by the system. (This vastly oversimplifies what's actually happening, and can only really be considered accurate for the sake of end results within your specific context.)

With `tmux`, that arrangement is turned on its ear. `tmux` is designed to let you start a shell, then disconnect from that session to log out and log back in later and reconnect to the same session. Thus, it keeps its children alive despite its parent being killed.

In your case specifically, you start with one process, the `bash` process. That is your current shell. When you invoke `tmux`, your current shell starts a child called `tmux`, and `tmux` automatically starts a child `bash` of itself. This second `bash` is where you ran your `ps` command. When you kill your original shell's `tmux`, you don't actually kill the `tmux` session, only that connection to it. Thus, your grandchild shell remains running, in the `tmux` session, and you're dumped back into you parent shell.

See the `tmux` man pages for how to connect to an existing `tmux` session or disconnect from it, as well as how to more effectively use `tmux`.

Comment: `ps` without options wouldn't show the bash process that tmux ran from: by default `ps` only shows processes running on the current terminal. But it's not clear from the question whether NNNComplex ran `ps`, or perhaps `ps` with options.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I ran `ps` without options. So does that mean that one of the two bash processes I see isn't the parent terminal? It appears to have the same PID.

Comment: Thanks John, I found your post helpful. By running `tmux attach`, I was able to reattach to that session and `Ctrl+D` to properly close that session.

Can you if there is a way of closing it without having to first use `tmux attach`? Why wasn't I able to use `kill` to end that session?

Comment: “Normally, when you kill a process, all of it's children processes are reaped (killed) by the system.” No, that's completely wrong. Any automatic killing that happens would be based on the disappearance of the terminal, or on a signal handler in a shell, not on a mere parent-child relationship.

Comment: Vastly simplified to focus on end results within this context, and admittedly technically not perfect (much like Newton is imperfect about physics), but I dispute the "completely wrong" characterization.